# What does the level do?

Tags: luftrausers

What does the level do in Luftrausers? Does your plane upgrade when you get to the next level, or is it just for looks?

Comment: Did you mean Luftrauser*s* or Luftrauser? They're different games (sort of) and you used them interchangeably so I assumed you meant the former...

Comment: Luftrausers, main website : http://luftrausers.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do nothing. You get an achievement when you reach level 10 but that's it. It doesn't affect anything in the gameplay.